# Mysql min function returning incorrect result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Book_Details table

```
CREATE TABLE `Book_Details` (
  `bookId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `book_desc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this table contains three rows

```
insert into book_details values (1,'Java for beginners','Java Book for beginners',99);
insert into book_details values (2,'Learn Advanced java','Advanced Java Book',223);
insert into book_details values (3,'Learn Practical java','Practical Java Book',78);
```

While I am executing the below query

```
select min(price) min_price,book_name from book_details;
```

I was expecting below result

```
min_price | book_name
-----------------------
78        | Learn Practical java
```

but surprisingly I am getting below output

```
min_price | book_name
-----------------------
78        | Java for beginners
```

Could someone please explain me why I am getting this output? Where I am wrong? 
My MYsql DB version is 5.5.38. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SELECT statement is not proper SQL but MySQL accepts it. The query always returns a single row, but several books may have the same price and the query could return any of the `book_name` values. You should use a SELECT that returns multiple rows for all the books that have the minimum price

```
select price,book_name from book_details where price = (select min(price) from book_details)
```

Answer (score 4):

You get the minimum price and arbitrary values for the other columns.  You are using a MySQL extension that you should just simply stop using -- always be sure that all columns in the `select` that are not arguments to aggregation functions -- are in the `group by`.

Try this instead:

```
select bd.*
from book_details
order by price
limit 1;
```

Comment: Note that even with this example, if multiple rows have the same price, the SQL standard doesn't guarantee which row you'll get. If you want consistency, include a unique column in the ORDER BY clause. If you don't have a unique column, you should probably add one (and make it the primary key).